# Buttons and Images not rendering wight height in safari

Tags: css, reactjs, image, button, bootstrap-4

I have no idea whats going on here... My react project uses reactstrap and bootstrap.
It works fine in chrome, but in safari, images are not loading and buttons are appearing at half the height they should.

I have tested it out with regular HTML5 buttons as well and adjusted the height of images... but it seems nothing has helped. Since it didn't make a differnece with the standard HTML5 buttons, I am assuming it's not a problem with bootstrap but I could be wrong...

Any ideas of where to look??

Edit* Kind of fixed it - I had the modal set at a height of 90vh. I commented it out and now it works. Obviously the modal overflows the screen, but at least the content inside is working agian. Let me know if ya'll know why safari is doing this!

[image: Safari View]
[image: Chrome View]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, Safari does have some issues understanding the `vh` unit.

If you still want to use `vh`, I'd recommend that you use this neat trick mentioned on CSS tricks: https://css-tricks.com/the-trick-to-viewport-units-on-mobile/.

In your case, where you're using `90vh`, you can try

```
.modal-element {
  height: 90vh; /* Fallback for browsers that do not support Custom Properties */
  height: calc(var(--vh, 1vh) * 90);
}
```

Post that, you can set this variable via JavaScript.

```
// First we get the viewport height and we multiple it by 1% to get a value for a vh unit
let vh = window.innerHeight * 0.01;
// Then we set the value in the --vh custom property to the root of the document
document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--vh', `${vh}px`);
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: It sure does! Thanks for the help! I was just commenting out random things to figure out what was causing the issue. Glad I found it and learned a bit about VH and safari. - It's crazy, I am working on a second app as well that has no problems with VH in safari! -- Thanks agian!

Comment: Glad to be of help!
And well, you know what they say, "Everything in Africa bites, but the Safari Bug is the worst of all!"